# Почему питон ругается на аргумент?

Tags: python

Всю голову сломал, вроде все правильно делаю. Получаю объект (sh) и передаю его в функцию (метод класса), но почему то ругается на позиционный аргумент:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
def receive_shot(self):
        sx = self.x
        sy = self.y
        radar.count_shot += 1

        if type(temp.board[sx][sy]) == Ship:
            sh = temp.board[sx][sy]
            sh.len_ship -= 1


            if sh.len_ship <= 0:
                Board.mark_destroyed_ship(sh)
                return sh

            radar.board[sx][sy] = Cell.damaged_ship
            return 'get'

        else:
            radar.board[sx][sy] = Cell.miss_cell
            return 'miss'
```

Метод (вернее его начало, чтобы не загромаждать):

```
def mark_destroyed_ship(self, sh):

        field = radar.board

        x, y = sh.x, sh.y
        width, height = sh.width, sh.height
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: у вас `recieve_shot` не всегда возвращает `sh`-объект. Может в этом причина? Вы уверены что передаете объект `sh`? и к вам не прилетает строка `miss` или `get`?

Comment: Функция Board.mark_destroyed_ship(sh) запускается только тогда, когда объект - sh.

Comment: `mark_destroyed_ship(sh = sh)` не поможет?

Comment: Подсказали. Нужно применять метод не к классу, а к объекту класса.

Answer (score 0):

Подсказали. Нужно применять метод не к классу, а к объекту класса.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]